# Why do the rankings from U.S. News & World Report list some schools twice?

Tags: graduate-school, education, ranking

The 2014 rankings of US statistics doctoral programs compiled by the *U.S. News & World Report* lists a few of the schools twice. I assume that the rankings are probably for different types of statistics programs (Harvard for example has both a statistics department but also a very good School of Public Health, which I'm sure has a biostatistics program), but the methodology section does not address this problem and I am doing research which requires analysis of this list.

**Question:**  Why are some schools listed twice in the rankings?

I cannot request this information from *U.S. News & World Report* directly because they only release this information to university officials.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you click on a school's name, you can see the rankings of its various departments, including both Statistics and Biostatistics if applicable ([example](https://www.usnews.com/best-graduate-schools/top-science-schools/university-of-washington-seattle-campus-236948)). This is pretty inconvenient, as it requires going through the schools one-by-one, but I'm not sure there's a better way to get that information.

There is also a [post](https://forum.thegradcafe.com/topic/52537-2014-usnwr-rankings-statisticsbiostatistics/?p=1058104599) on gradcafe separating the rankings, though I'm not sure if it includes the entire list.